# Teradata Dynamic Insert - Looped?

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm doing something very similar to dnoeth's second comment on this question:

[Insert Into table Teradata dynamic stored procedure SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36866076/insert-into-table-teradata-dynamic-stored-procedure-sql)

I need to run it multiple times to loop the same insert statement but with different values for the "?" and I'm not sure how to go about that.

The dynamic value in my version is a date span. I can't run a massive insert without spooling out so I've broken the data into segments.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to use a cursor. define a cursor and store the date values in the cursor variables and loop through the cursor. That should solve your problem.

Comment: I'd suggest trying to figure out why you're spooling out, or look into TPT or FastLoad.

Comment: Yes, a cursor sounds like the solution. The problem is that I'm not sure what the EXECUTE part looks like in a cursor. How do I re-use the same object from the PREPARE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

William,

As you are aware that you need to use cursor to iterate through each value you want to process.

For that purpose store dynamically created INSERT statement into a variable.

Final step: Use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` command to run insert statement stored in teradata variable

Here is the working sample that you may refer

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE td_user.sp_dynamic_insert( OUT proc_msg VARCHAR(5000) )
BEGIN

DECLARE lv_insert_txt      VARCHAR(20000);

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN          
/* Error handling code if required */
END;

L0: 
FOR insert_cursor AS select_list
CURSOR FOR    
    SELECT Col2 
    FROM   test_1

DO  
   SET lv_insert_txt = 'INSERT INTO test_2(Col1,Col2) VALUES('||TRIM(insert_cursor.Col2)||','||TRIM(insert_cursor.Col2)||')';


   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_insert_txt;
END FOR L0;

SET proc_msg = 'Procedure completed successfully';
END;
```